# Error in loading JSON data -JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, jsondecodeerror

I am trying to get json data in a container using following code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=NIFTY&identifier=FUTIDXNIFTY29-02-2024XX0.00'

headers = {
        'accept':'*/*',
        'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
        'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
         }

session = requests.Session()

data = session.get(url, headers = headers).json()
```

It throws me following error:

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Because what is inside `session.get(url, headers = headers)` is not json.

Comment: It contains this html code :
`<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang="en">\r\n<head>\r\n  <meta charset="UTF-8">\r\n  <title>Resource not found</title>\r\n</head>\r\n<body style="background-color: #e8e8e8;">\r\n  <div style="font-size: 32px; padding: 50px 25px; text-align: center;">\r\n    Resource not found\r\n  </div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Then what it is and how to convert that data into a data frame.

Comment: The website did not recognize your request.  Maybe you used the wrong url, maybe you used the wrong stock symbol, maybe the website was having technical trouble, there's no way to tell what the problem is.

Comment: As @JohnGordon well said, I can't tell what is the root of your problem. but it seems there is a problem with your url

Comment: But in browser I am getting the data.

Comment: Also if not in this way but in another way can I get the data in a data frame.

Comment: "But in browser I am getting data" - if you see data when you visit this URL, you must be visiting another server than us https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=NIFTY&identifier=FUTIDXNIFTY29-02-2024XX0.00 (that's the URL in your code, and it doesn't lead to anything - unless you have some local DNS/hosts setting that does indeed send you to another server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR --> Add cookies to the request

The website just checks if the request you have sent has the right cookies. So a good approach to get the information is to copy your cookies and adding it into your request. Here's a PoC (I didn't use `requests.session`, and I've redacted the actual values of cookies, but you should be able to implement this approach in your code):

```py
import requests

cookies = {
    "nsit": "Redacted",
    "AKA_A2": "Redacted",
    "_ga": "Redacted",
    "nseQuoteSymbols": "Redacted",
    "ak_bmsc": "Redacted",
    "_ga_QJZ4447QD3": "Redacted",
    "defaultLang": "Redacted",
    "nseappid": "Redacted",
    "RT": "Redacted",
    "_ga_87M7PJ3R97": "Redacted",
    "bm_sv": "Redacted"
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.nseindia.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=NIFTY&identifier=FUTIDXNIFTY29-02-2024XX0.00',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A',
}
response = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=NIFTY&identifier=FUTIDXNIFTY29-02-2024XX0.00', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

Now of course the cookies won't be `redacted`, I hid it because of privacy reasons. If you do similar approach your code will work out.

Comment: Glad it worked! Good luck. Note that the cookies sometimes will expire, so you have to update them from time to time depending on that website.